# execution time is coming worng in extent report v4.03 with selenium with c#

Tags: extentreports

i am using extent report v4.03. It is showing wrong time for the execution of test on the dashboard view. total execution time for test is 24 seconds but it shows 27 s. also in test view the time is coming wrong. how can i correct the same.

Also please let me know how can i display time for each step.

i am using selenium,specflow and nunit. language:c#

Answer (score 0):

The actual time it takes to run the individual tests could be 24 seconds with the fixture/suite setup/teardown taking an additional 3 seconds. Anything that happens before and after a test is counted towards the global timing but not towards the individual test time.

When running tests, its important to consider how much time is spent during a run *not* running tests. Which is what I assume is where you're getting the additional 3 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.the additional time increases when the number of test increase and the difference is quite large between the actual run time(what vsts test explorer shows) and what is coming in the report. Also vsts test explorer time is the actual run time not individual test time. Is there a way to show correct time that is what is coming in the vsts test explorer. Also can you let me know how can i display time for individual step. currently report shows 0.000 in individual step

Comment: So extent report shows a shorter time than VSTS? The VSTS time is most likely correct. It will take into account the total time it takes to start the setup > run > and teardown your SpecFlow tests. Whereas the extent report will show the timing where you tell it to start and where you tell it to end.There is a lot more going on behind SpecFlow that is not interfaced to the consumer, which is where the extra time is coming from.

Comment: Where are you logging your step timing to get that 0.000? You should have a before step and after step hook that starts and stops a timer and logs the duration in the after step hook.

Comment: Extent report is showing a longer time than vsts which is not the correct time. Is there a way that i can log the correct time that vsts shows. Also i have these after step and before step attributes but i am not logging 0.00 it is coming by default. I dont want to use timers. Is there a way in extent report by which the time for each step can be logged.

Comment: Any solution to above mentioned issue